# Are higher-order beings called by the divine in their actions?

Tags: metaphysics, transcendent

It seems from observation that one of the hallmark signs of a higher being (one that is in close unity with the divine with respect to their actions and thoughts) is that they tend to have a transcendental instinct for meaning and life in general, where the typical man whose disjoint with the divine tends to act either rationally or impulsively, the transcendental instinct of the higher being provides him a certain spiritual realm with a degree of psychic ability—ability to decipher danger, ability to decipher accurately between good and evil, making inferences that cannot be deduced by logic and by the scientific method. It seems that the higher being is called to their actions rather than them acting solely based on a sequence of deterministic causes. A certain type of free will with a transcendental basis.

Comment: What exactly is the question here and what is the text that made you think about this?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking The question is the title: whether there is a marked difference in the exhibition of behaviour of higher-order beings (as defined above) and the ordinary man with respect to the manifestation of meaning. It’s in part an inquiry into the relationship of religion and the portrayal of the transcendental.

Comment: Anyway if you read over the link to book below you will see  Hesse, Jung, Nietzsche. And your higher order man has similarities to a Zarathustra type figure. Perhaps.

Comment: Has 4 close votes already, so it seems moot. But... What makes you think divine beings are more sensible than ordinary humans? Yaweh? Read the story of Brides for the Tribe of Benjamin. Greek/Roman pantheon? Read about Zeus and his various human consorts. Egyptian pantheon? How many parts was that guy divided into? Chinese pantheon? Whee! The Monkey King! I could go on, but I have to go have dinner with Pig.

Comment: High-order being? Angels, superheroes?

Answer (score 1):

Have you been reading some Herman Hesse or something on that order?  For some reason “Narcissus and Goldmund”?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_and_Goldmund

You might want to research Hesse.

I’m American born, I don’t know that Americans can ever get the proper feeling for and comprehension of Hesse.

Right now your question seems a little “dreamy”.  And that’s okay. But it may not be in a form where we can give you an intelligible answer. Or maybe I’m wrong and someone will correct me.

Hesse: “As reflected in Demian, and other works, he believed that "for different people, there are different ways to God...” Wikipedia

In Christianity there is God (Trinity),  Angels, Man. I don’t think there is a formal “higher order man”. Some men are better than others. More saintly etc. But they are NOT of a different KIND from any other man.